# Could countries rejoin a new Soviet Union?

Tags: european-union, soviet-union

Since countries like Hungary and Poland are having arguments with the EU at the moment about things like immigration, might they quit the EU or even be pushed away towards Russia and a new Soviet Union?

Perhaps it would be a Soviet Union that was run more like the EU where states voluntarily joined. An "Eastern-European Union" if you will.

What are the arguments that would prevent a country like Hungary going into a union with Russia?

Comment: Simplest argument: Hungary doesn’t want it.

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but neither Poland not Hungary were ever part of the USSR.

Comment: What do you mean by "a new Soviet Union"? The Soviet Union is a proper noun - it is a specific thing that existed in a certain time. Can you be more specific about what you are asking for?

Comment: @Indigochild I suppose in the same way that New York is a new York and New Wales is a new Wales!

Comment: That isn't clear to me. Are you suggesting a legal re-creation of the first Soviet Union? Or a new treaty with some similar provisions? Or some other kind of international framework? As it stands, the question is very vague. It's hard to know what kind of factual information would answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking more of something like Comecon, the Eastern European communist common market?

Comment: Maybe a new Iron Curtain, not a new Soviet Union.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it already exists. It's called The [Eurasian Economic Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_Economic_Union).

As to why Hungary might not join it. Well the whole thing has a nominal GDP of of $1.48 Trillion most of which comes from Russia s GDP. The  [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) has a nominal GDP of $18.4 Trillion. So Hungarian wallets profit more from being in the EU.

Answer (score 0):

The argument might be an economic one.

the EU economy and market is a lot more stronger than Russia's.

https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?locations=RU-EU

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Russia has long advocated a former-USSR free association union (for various meanings of the word "free"). Several were formed (Tamozhenny soyuz, CIS, CSTO, etc....).

Part of the whole invasion of Crymea/Ukraine/Maidan stuff was over Ukraine choosing EU integration path over Russia integration path.